# std::unordered_set - в какой элемент помещается значение

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста про хеш-таблицы std::unordered_set/std::unordered_map

Я никак не могу понять, ну вот есть:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string>my_unordered = { "AAAA","BBBB", "BBBF1");
```

То есть теперь имеет заполненный std::unordered_set - тремя элементами.
Я не могу понять, как идет заполнение выделение памяти.
Я добавляю первый элемент "AAAA" он же и ключ, как я понял некая хеш-функция принимает на вход это значение "AAAA" и на выходе выдает самое хеш-значение, НО, как это хеш значение связывается с реальным элементом std::unordered_set??

То есть в каком "элементе" выделенной памяти - теперь будет находится значение "AAAA" ??? Добавлено только три элемента, то есть от 0 до 2, не выдаст же хеш-функция значение от 0 до 2 ??

Что то я запутался окончательно. :(

Comment: `не выдаст же хеш-функция значение от 0 до 2` Оператор взятия остатка творит чудеса: `hash{}("AAAA") % inner_vector_size`.

Comment: @wololo, я наверное про это и спрашиваю, потому что ни как не могу въехать, что на выходе то получается и как ? Ну для примера, если я возьму std::hash от "AAAA" - то будет 9890857558446683929, но это же в качестве элемента в "массиве" нельзя использовать. Вот и не въезжаю, как это работает.

Comment: Индекс элемента во внутреннем массиве — это `hash_value % inner_vector_size`. Если хеш-функция вернёт `9890857558446683929`, а размер внутреннего массива равен `3`, то искомый индекс — это `9890857558446683929 % 3 == 1`.

Comment: @wololo, спасибо. А что происходит при добавлении элементов ? Ведь размер std::unordered_set - меняется и значение sh{}("AAAA") % inner_vector_size - с каждый разам будет разным в зависимости от размера. Не пересчитывается же каждый раз - это значение при добавлении элементов же ?

Comment: Внутренний массив берётся с запасом. Его размер равен [`bucket_count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/bucket_count). В основном, добавление элемента не приводит к изменению величины `hash_value % bucket_count`. Но если отношение ([`load_factor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/load_factor)) количества элементов (`size`) в контейнере к размеру внутреннего массива (`bucket_count`) становится больше порогового значения ([`max_load_factor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/max_load_factor)), ...

Comment: ... то тогда выделяется новый внутренний массив большего размера. Соответственно пересчитываются индексы элементов `unordered_set`'а, и эти элементы перемещаются в новый внутренний массив. [Небольшой пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f3bcbde8f75ba2d).